# JMeter results size limit

Tags: jmeter

I am running a stability test (60hrs) in Jmeter.  I have several graphs in the test plan to capture system resources like cpu, threads, heap.

The size of `View_Results_Tree.xml` file is 9GB after 24hrs. I am afraid if jmeter will sustain for 60hrs.

1. Is there size limit for `View_Results_Tree.xml` or results folder size in Jmeter?
2. What are the best practices to be followed in Jmeter before running such long tests?  I am looking for recommended config/properties for such long tests.

Thanks
Veera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no results file limit as long as it fits into your hard drive for storing or in your RAM to open and analyze.

The [general recommendations are](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean):

1. Use CSV format instead of XML
2. Store only those metrics which you **need** to store, saving unnecessary stuff causes massive memory and disk IO overheads.

If you look into *jmeter.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder) for properties which names start with `jmeter.save.saveservice` i.e.

```
#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
#etc.
```

Copy them all to *user.properties* file, set "interesting" properties to `true` and others to `false` - that will allow to save a lot of disk space and release valuable resources for the load testing itself.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for more detailed explanation of the above recommendations and few more JMeter performance tuning tweaks.

Comment: `code`
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
`code`

Comment: Above properties are set to true in my user.properties file and output format is set to csv.  However, after 36hrs into the test size of View_Results_Tree.xml is 16G.  active_threads_over_time.csv,  gr-hits_per_second.csv,  results-gr.csv, and trans_per_sec.csv - these files are created in results folder.
Which files are expected to be in csv format with output_format set to csv in user.properties file?

Comment: Ideally you should have a single .jtl results file. If aforementioned files are generated by the [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) - disable these listeners. Once your test finishes open .jtl results file with the listener of your choice and you will be able to see all the metrics. There is no need to have separate result files. Moreover, [listeners have negative impact on overall JMeter performance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing).

Comment: I am wondering how View_Results_Tree.xml is created when i have output_format=csv.

Answer (score 1):

There are not limits on file size in JMeter, the limit is your your disk space.
From the file name, I guess you chose XML output, it is better to choose CSV output (see below another reason for that).

Besides, ensure you're not using GUI for load testing in JMeter which is a bad practice, this will certainly break your test if you do it.

Switch to Non GUI mode and ensure you follow those [recommendations](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/).

> /bin/jmeter -t  -n -l /results.csv

Since JMeter 3.0, you can even generate report at end of load test of from an existing CSV (JTL, not from XML format) file, see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

As you need GUI for monitoring, run Jmeter in GUI mode only for the monitoring part.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information.  I am running my 60hrs test in command line.
Like in Loadrunner, Is there any way to control the graph sampling rate in Jmeter?

Comment: If you want to play on sampling rate. to reduce size, it won't do it. You should open an enhancement request at JMeter and describe the expected feature

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer provided by UBIK LOAD PACK. But in case if you need to have the results stored somewhere you don't need to worry about the size of the file. The best solution is using Grafana and Graphite (InfluxDB) for realtime reports and efficient storage.